# Checkbox ActiveForm Yii2

Tags: php, html, yii2, active-form

i want to change default value of checkbox.
so when checked the value that will be stored in the database = 0, whereas if unchecked the data stored in the database = 1

I've seen some examples like

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'agent_email_verification')->checkbox(['checked' => $model->agent_email_verification > 0,  'value' => true]) ?>
```

and

```
<?php $model->status = 1; ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'status')->checkbox()->label('Hi'); ?>
```

but when I save it to the database the values ​​I get are still checked = 1, uncheck = 0

Can you help me

I expect if i save data i get value checked = 0, uncheck = 1

Comment: Check the value within the controller to see what you've received, and you can manage this within the model's beforeSave method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose there's the `uncheck` option. Try

`<?= $form->field($model, 'status')->checkbox(['value' => 0, 'uncheck' => '1']); ?>`

See: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-activefield#checkbox()-detail